# SQL - LEFT JOIN on customer id

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join

I have to join two tables on the customer_id column. Seems simple enough, but when I run my query, I receive no results. I've provided an example below of my data: table_1, table_2, and desired_end_results.

Table 1 has more dimensions than Table 2. Basically, what I want to do is match cust_id from Table 2 to Table 1 and then join in the Table 2 metric. (Is this possible?)

**Table_1:**

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust_id | dimension | 1234 |
| date | date | 2021-05-01 |
| country | dimension | US |
| platform | dimension | ios |
| campaign | dimension | ABC |
| ad_name | dimension | ABC |
| ad_set | dimension | ABC |
| platform_a_revenue | metric | 100 |

**Table_2:**

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust_id | dimension | 1234 |
| date | date | 2021-05-01 |
| country | dimension | US |
| platform | dimension | ios |
| platform_b_revenue | metric | 50 |

**desired_end_results:**

| Name | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cust_id | dimension | 1234 |
| date | date | 2021-05-01 |
| country | dimension | US |
| platform | dimension | ios |
| campaign | dimension | ABC |
| ad_name | dimension | ABC |
| ad_set | dimension | ABC |
| platform_a_revenue | metric | 100 |
| platform_b_revenue | metric | 50 |

I've tried writing some queries, but I am receiving no results. I believe I have to use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT 
cust_id, date, country, platform, campaign, ad_name, ad_set, platform_a_revenue, platform_b_revenue 
FROM table_1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 
USING (cust_id)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be very helpful. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do the tables only have one row each?!?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a prioritization query, where you want everything in `table_1` and then non-matches in `table_2`.  If so, you want `union all`:

```
select name, type, value
from table_1
union all
select name, type, value
from table_t2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_1 t1
                  where t1.name = t2.name and t1.type = t2.type
                 );
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I would like everything in table_1 and then the platform_b_revenue metric from table 2, and I would like to join that on appsflyer_id. 

I attempted your query above and received the following error: Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count; query 1 has 16 columns, query 2 has 5 columns

Comment: @vtrhmd . . . The queries in this answer have exactly the same columns.

Answer (score 0):

for union operator you need same columns number in both table. Maybe you can try full join and then filter results (using for example where no exists as suggested above?). Not sure about your goal.